# How do I configure Jenkins to strip the leading "origin/" in git branch parameter?

Tags: regex, git, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with a branch parameter to specify the branch to build from.  Other stuff downstream needs the branch name to not have the leading "origin/" -- just "feature/blahblah" or "bugfix/12345" or similar.  The advanced settings for the parameter let me specify a branch filter via regex, but I'm a regex newbie and the solutions I've found in searching are language-dependent.  The Jenkins documentation for this is sparse.

When a user clicks on "build with parameters", for the branch I want to see branch names that omit the leading "origin/".  I'm not sure how to write a regex for Jenkins that will "consume" that part of the branch name before setting the parameter value.

I solved this problem once before, I'm pretty sure using Stack Overflow, but I can't find those hints now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For the git branch parameter, set Branch Filter to:

```
origin/(.*)
```

I found the parentheses to be counter-intuitive, because if you don't specify a filter you get:

```
.*
```

(No parens.)  If you are filtering stuff out, you use parens to indicate the part to keep.

Comment: Exactly what I was after when Jenkins was trying to checkout from origin/origin/some-branch. +1

Comment: I have a blacklist like branch filter: ^(?!(origin\/(fuer_Jenkins_PD_cep_res))$).*$
This solution doesn't work for me. Do you know how I can get rid if the "origin/" prefix in the dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to filter multiple patterns without origin/ section, try the following.

```
origin/(develop.*|feature.*|bugfix.*)
```

This will list the develop, feature and bugfix branches without the leading *origin/*.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a groovy script evaluated before the job, like:

```
def map = [:]
map['GIT_BRANCH'] = GIT_BRANCH - 'origin/'
return map
```

This is using the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), as described in [gitlab-plugin issue 444](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/444#issuecomment-270455503)